# Sublime Text 3 custom select list for general-purpose autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, sublime-text-3

### Select list for 'multiple-choice' style input

For Sublime Text 3, is there a plugin or package that enables the creation of custom-made select drop-down lists?

The goal is something that works with *any* type of file (even plain text files) and not based on any specific programming language or syntax.

This question *almost* addresses the question,

( [Autocompletion for custom PHP classes in Sublime Text 2/3](https://superuser.com/questions/958552/autocompletion-for-custom-php-classes-in-sublime-text-2-3) )

but it is based on a specific language (PHP) ... the goal here is different -- to support *any* language ... or even just plain text.

### Example image

[Example image simulating custom select list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd5BJ.png)

### Related

- https://sublimetext.userecho.com/communities/1/topics/1848-multiple-choice-for-snippetautocompletion-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create autocompletions and snippets that are scope-agnostic.

### Autocompletions

You can store multiple autocompletions in one file. Save your custom autocompletions to the `Packages/User` folder as `filename.sublime-completions`. You can find out the exact location of that folder by running *Browse Packages* from the command palette.

```
{
    "scope": "source,text",

    "completions":
    [
        { "trigger": "hello_world", "contents": "Hello ${1:World}" },
        { "trigger": "bye_world", "contents": "Bye ${1:World}" },
    ]
}
```

### Snippet

Snippets behave very similar to autocompletions, but can only contain one "completion". Also the trigger is much stricter as for autocompletions. The easiest way to create a snippet is the *New Snippet* option from the *Tools→Developer* menu, since it will automatically use `Packages/User` as the default file target.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
Hello ${1:World}
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>hello_world</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

Note that I've omitted the scope tag to make the snippet work universally. You can use `text.plain` to make it work in plain text *only*.

### Further Notes

Both examples above contain tab-stops. These are basically jump points that can contain placeholder text (e.g. `${1:World}`) or not (e.g. `$1`). Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to jump between tab-stops. The order is defined by the numbers used each tab-stop.

Comment: This makes sense. The missing part for me was the ability to create a sublime-completions file where the completions all start with a common string prefix. This enables select-lists that can be triggered by typing in the common prefix, such as `greet_hello_world, greet_bye_world, greet_new_world, greet_old_world` ... "greet" becomes the common trigger-abbreviation. Thanks for the answer!